# Akeneo - How do I export product data given an invalid mailer URL error?

Tags: akeneo, pim

I have an Akeneo PIM set up in a bitnami instance.  I have created categories, attributes, a family, a channel, and some products.  Every export file I generate comes with the error `Cannot create a SenderAddress with an invalid mailer URL`. However, category and attribute exports still get generated, populated as expected.

Product data exports, on the other hand, get the `Cannot create a SenderAddress with an invalid mailer URL` error but then generate empty spreadsheets.

I only have access to the Akeneo web interface, although my manager can SSH into the server.  How can I solve the mailer URL error, and how can I generate product data exports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two steps to solving this.

First, listing a valid mailer URL in the .env file resolved the invalid mailer URL error.

Second,from https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/10389.

The problem was that none of the products had been assigned categories yet, and a feature of Akeneo is that only products with categories are included in any product data export.

Assigning categories to products enabled non-empty product data exports.